# Use caching in PHP for web app?

Tags: php, ajax, caching, memcached

I'm considering building a simple game with PHP as its backbone, but rather than doing a bunch of post redirects like classic web games this one will involve more immediate responses through ajax. In order to achieve what I want though, I think I'll want to store some information (locations of players, for instance) in server memory as opposed to a database. Should I use a caching library like Memcached or APA for this, or is there an alternative that will work better?

Comment: If you're caching the informations in server memory, they'll be lost if the server is restarting (or crashes and restarts).

Comment: I'm not here to bash PHP, I quite love it, but for statefull cross-user dynamic data, are you sure it's the tool for the job? I'd much quicker choose node or a java server for the requirements you mention, and for gaming purposes I'd sooner choose websockets if available then classic ajax.

Comment: I was highly considering websockets, but the only issue with that is I won't be able to host it on any of my hosting plans. It's definitely the better option when available though, I agree. I could also have php scripts interface with a python script or Java program, but I'm not sure if that will make much difference as opposed to using memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is a great tool for caching data because it's very fast and has a simple interface, but if the data you want to store needs to slightly more permanent and you cannot recreate it if it is lost, I would recommend something more durable. I have used Membase (same interface as memcached, but is persisted to disk eventually) and Redis (more robust interface including lists and a whole lot more).

Bottom line, if it's information you have stored in some other place but you just want to keep fast access to it, memcached is great. If you want something lighter than SQL but it will be the only place the information is stored, try some other NoSQL solution.